# manner clause or relative clause?

Tags: grammar

> I travel to the Binhai New Area by light railway every day, **as do many businessmen who live in downtown Tianjin**.

In the above sentence, does "as do many businessmen who live in downtown Tianjin" serve as a manner clause or relative clause?

Thank you very much!

Comment: A concessive clause suggests a meaning opposite to the main clause. For example, "I ride by bicycle to the Binhai New Area, even though most businessmen walk." A relative clause needs "who" or one of its forms to connect it to the main clause. In your example, "who live in downtown Tianjin" is a relative clause.

Answer (score 1):

Neither, it is a dependent clause. A depenent clause is a part of a sentence that if it stood alone wouldn't make sense and relies on the other side of the sentence which does make sense by itself.